# Javascript Random Images and its link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, src

I plan to have 1 image load at one time, and with it, have it's appropriate link. I would like it to write the image into a div with an ID of 'ads'. Here is what I have so far. I'm just not advanced enough in JavaScript in order to make it do what I want :P. Each link array value is the same as the image src array. So img[0] and link[0] belong together.

What I would like it to do is find the image, and then append the URL along with it, so that when the image is clicked, it will go to that site. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-size: 32px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Reload the page to see different images</h1>
    <h2>Click an image for a link.</h2>
    <div id="ads">
    <!--image link/src here-->
</div>
</body>
</html>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var image = new Array ();
image[0] = "<img src='images/img1.png'></a>";
image[1] = "<img src='images/img2.jpg'></a>";
image[2] = "<img src='images/img3.jpg'></a>";
image[3] = "<img src='images/img4.jpg'></a>";

var link = new Array ();
    link[0] = "<a href='http://www.gooogle.com' target='_blank'>";
    link[1] = "<a href='http://www.shade-designs.com' target='_blank'>";
    link[2] = "<a href='http://www.sharpnackford' target='_blank'>";
    link[3] = "<a href='http://www.donleyford.com' target='_blank'>";

var size = image.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
link = x;
document.getElementById('ads').appendChild(link).src=image[x];
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you're appending an array to the div, which has no src attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have anything extra within ads div `innerHTML` will overwrite it.So better to use append:

```
$('#ads').append(link[x]+image[x]);
```

### [See this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8GwQh/)

Comment: Even better. I will have to use this in a different web site with content inside of nested divs, so this applies to my needs better. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
link = x;
document.getElementById('ads').appendChild(link).src=image[x];
```

do:

```
document.getElementById('ads').innerHTML = link[x] + image[x];
```

Comment: If you want to append the image, change `=` to `+=`